# How to turn off electric-indent-mode for specific Major mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, major-mode

I have few Major modes (like: Yaml and NXML) that I don't want electric-indent-mode (I want it for C like languages) but I'm unable to turn if off. To enable I have:

```
(electric-indent-mode 1)
```

from documentation (for variable electric-indent-mode)

> Non-nil if Electric-Indent mode is enabled.
>   See the command `electric-indent-mode' for a description of this minor mode.
>   Setting this variable directly does not take effect;
>   either customize it (see the info node`Easy Customization')
>   or call the function `electric-indent-mode'.

and for a function

> Toggle on-the-fly reindentation (Electric Indent mode). With a prefix
>   argument ARG, enable Electric Indent mode if ARG is positive, and
>   disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable the mode if ARG is
>   omitted or nil.

so I try to turn it off in a hook:

```
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook (lambda ()                        
                             (electric-indent-mode -1)))
```

(Actualy I use after-change-major-mode-hook and check `(memql major-mode '(yaml-mode python-mode nxml-mode))` where I can add more modes to the list).

But it don't work, I've also try:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'electric-indent-mode) nil)
```

No joy. But it work when I eval `(electric-indent-mode -1)` from .emacs files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With a recent Emacs (probably Emacs snapshot only) you can use `electric-indent-local-mode`, e.g.:

```
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-indent-local-mode -1)))
```

If your Emacs lacks this function, you can still sort of disable the mode via `electric-indent-functions`, e.g.

```
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (add-hook 'electric-indent-functions
                            (lambda () 'no-indent) nil 'local)))
```

And in either case, you may probably want to restore `C-j`, via

```
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook 
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-j") #'newline-and-indent)))
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me with the same problem, only with enh-ruby-mode instead of yaml-mode. I'm too used to using the C-j behavior to want to change now, but understand why it might be good for newcomers to have electric-indent on by default.

Answer (score 4):

`electric-indent-mode` will be enabled by default in 24.4.  To turn it off locally, you will be able to use `electric-indent-local-mode` as mentioned by lunaryorn.  But to turn it off locally in 24.3, you can do:

```
(add-hook 'foo-mode-hook
          (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'electric-indent-mode) nil)))
```

You mentioned that the first form didn't work for you, but it should (i.e. if it doesn't, it's because of the some other problem).

Comment: What stands against setting `electric-indent-functions` directly, as in my answer?

Comment: Oh, right, didn't see that one, sorry, indeed setting `electric-indent-functions` like you did also should do the trick.

Comment: Don't work for me, When I hit enter (or run `new-line`) the current line get indent.

Comment: My example code will only work for `foo-mode`.  "Don't work for me" doesn't give much information about what you've actually done, and my crystal ball is out for repairs.

Answer (score 2):

At least on emacs 24.3 you cannot disable electric indent mode locally, since it is a `global-mode`. Anyways the issue with `yaml-mode` is that the `electric-indent` functionality is built into it i.e. it will be enabled even without `electric-indent-mode`. The package does not provide a way to turn this behaviour off, maybe you should file an issue on its github repo.

Try this to disable the electric-indent functionality in `yaml-mode`

```
(define-key yaml-mode-map "|" nil)
(define-key yaml-mode-map ">" nil)
(define-key yaml-mode-map "-" nil)
(define-key yaml-mode-map "." nil)
(define-key yaml-mode-map [backspace] nil)
```

To restore the electric-indent behaviour afterwards, you can do

```
(define-key yaml-mode-map "|" 'yaml-electric-bar-and-angle)
(define-key yaml-mode-map ">" 'yaml-electric-bar-and-angle)
(define-key yaml-mode-map "-" 'yaml-electric-dash-and-dot)
(define-key yaml-mode-map "." 'yaml-electric-dash-and-dot)
(define-key yaml-mode-map [backspace] 'yaml-electric-backspace)
```

Comment: I have the same issue with NXML Mode and I can disable electric mode in Yaml mode. But as you said it's global mode and it don't work from hook.

Comment: @jcubic For `nxml mode` you can do `(define-key nxml-mode-map "/" nil)`.

Comment: Don't work for me, I run in from .emacs and from the nxml buffer and nothing. When I hit enter the current line get indent.

Comment: This should stop indenting on hitting `enter`, 

     `(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (add-hook 'electric-indent-functions
                            (lambda (pos) 'no-indent) nil 'local)))`

Comment: Isn't this append new function everytime I turn on nxml-mode?

Comment: Yes it would, to turn it off just once you can do `M-: (add-hook 'electric-indent-functions (lambda (pos) 'no-indent) nil 'local) RET`. To again re-enable do `M-: (remove-hook 'electric-indent-functions (lambda (pos) 'no-indent) t) RET`. You may want to wrap this in an interactive function if you are going to this frequently. BTW sorry for the formatting I don't know how to format code in comments.