# In Emacs, while editing a CMake file, how to turn off smart indentation?

Tags: emacs, cmake, indentation, emacs24, auto-indent

I just want each line to get the same indentation as the previous line, and that TAB would indent 4 spaces. For C++ I managed it with:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default c-syntactic-indentation nil)
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)
```

In my `.emacs`, but for CMake files Emacs just indents the lines automatically according to its own rules, and TAB has no effect at all.

Comment: If you're using `cmake-mode`, my answer should work. If your major mode is different, tell me and I'll try to work something out.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to disable is known as `electric-indent-mode` which is the function which indents your code when you press return. To disable it for `cmake-mode`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182550/how-to-turn-of-electric-indent-mode-for-specific-major-mode) is to include the following line in your `init`

```
(add-hook 'cmake-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-indent-local-mode -1)))
```

Comment: Thanx, but this has the effect that a new line has no indentation **at all**, and TAB still has no effect. I want each line to be idented exactly like the one before it, and TAB to insert 4 spaces.